# Grabbing a lock that's valid only once in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, locking

I'm using C++ 11, where I have 4 threads that are parallely inserting into a concurrent queue. I know when the threads are done processing, i.e. the expected final size of the queue.

Now, I want to perform a final aggregation operation on the contents of the queue that should be **strictly** performed **only once**. For example, say I want to aggregate the values and POST it to an external service.

How do I acquire a lock which is valid only once? I can't use a simple mutex because that would not guarantee me the only once requirement.

Pseudocode:

```
// inside a thread
enqueue items to concurrent_queue

if(concurrent_queue.size() == EXPECTED_SIZE) {
    // do something ONLY once
}
```

Comment: How about `std::call_once`?

Comment: you may want to use a latch, or a semaphore, where all threads try to acquire the lock after they're done with their processing, and once all have made that call, only one thread is released.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution.

```
if(concurrent_queue.size() == EXPECTED_SIZE) {
    // do something ONLY once
    static bool doItOnce = DoItOnceOnly();
}
```

Comment: This does require that all concurrent threads are the same function being run.  If not, you can refactor.  Note that the downside is that this is once per program execution, not once per operation or whatever.

Comment: @Yakk, that is right, but simply make all different threads call the same extra function which has the `static`.

Answer (score 2):

Check approach from Singleton implementations. The most basic:

```
bool executed = false;
void Execute() 
{
    Lock lock;      // scope-based lock, released automatically when the function returns
    if (executed == false) 
    {
       executed = true;
       //.. do computation
    }
}
```

Check also solutions with atomic variables and double-checked locking for better performance:
http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/

Comment: Yes, the bool should be global or class member. Propably near concurrent_queue declaration.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't concerned about the possibility of the operation failing, you can simply use an `atomic<bool>` that is associated with the operation. All of the threads will try to change the flag from `false` to `true` with [compare_exchange_strong](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange), but only one will succeed:

```
// inside a thread
enqueue items to concurrent_queue

if(concurrent_queue.size() == EXPECTED_SIZE) {
    std::atomic<bool>& flag = retrieve_the_associated_bool();
    bool expected = false;
    if (flag.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) {
      // do something
    }
}
```

If the operation can fail, you should use [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) and a `std::once_flag` associated with the operation. The other threads will wait while one tries to "do something", and each try in turn until one succeeds:

```
// inside a thread
enqueue items to concurrent_queue

if(concurrent_queue.size() == EXPECTED_SIZE) {
    std::once_flag& flag = retrieve_the_associated_once_flag();
    std::call_once(flag, []{
        // do something
    });
    // do something ONLY once
}
```